# Компилятор не различает конструктор по умолчанию и конструктор с ключевым словом params

Tags: c#, конструктор

Суть проблемы заключается в том, что если я создаю объект Progression
с пустыми скобками в конце, объект создается по конструктору (params float[]),
вместо выдачи ошибки, несмотря на то что конструктор по умолчанию я сделал приватным.

```cs
class Progression
    {
        public float FirstElement { get; }
        public float Difference { get; }

        private Progression()
        {
            
        }

        public Progression (float firstEl, float d)
        {
            FirstElement = firstEl;
            Difference = d;
        }

        public Progression (float firstEl, (float, int) randomEl)
        {
            FirstElement = firstEl;
            Difference = (randomEl.Item1 - firstEl) / (randomEl.Item2 - 1);
        }

        public Progression (Func<int, float> formula)
        {
            FirstElement = formula(1);
            Difference = formula(2) - formula(1);
        }

        public Progression (params float[] element)
        {
            FirstElement = element[0];
            Difference = element[1] - element[0];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Проверить длину массива на ноль и бросить исключение - не вариант? У вас вызывается не приватный конструктор, тот что params, просто массив element у вас будет пустой.

Comment: Да. Я ожидаю именно ошибку компиляции. Использовать массив это, я так понимаю, единственный вариант?

Comment: Ну вы сами выяснили, как работает params. Если вас устраивает  то используйте. Если нет, то выберите альтернативу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так работает `params`: пустой массив является частным случаем массива. Поэтому ваш вызов не может быть обслужен приватным конструктором (потому что он приватный), но может быть обслужен конструктором с `params`.

Если вы хотите, чтобы хотя бы один параметр в `params` был *обязательным*, вынесите его из `params`:

```
public Progression(float firstEl, params float[] restElements)
{
    FirstElement = firstEl;
    Difference = restElements[0] - firstEl;
}
```

Кстати, у вас и так есть конструктор с двумя `float`-аргументами, так что вызов `new Progression(1f, 1f)` вызовет конструктор `Progression(float firstEl, float d)`, а не `Progression(float firstEl, params float[] restElements)`. Это явно не то, что вам нужно, т. к. второй элемент будет проинтерпретирован не как член последовательности, а как разность.

А вот вызов конструктора с *одним* аргументом снова приведёт к пустому массиву и падению на `restElements[0]`. Так что вам по сути нужно *два* обязательных параметра.

---

Лучше воспользоваться идиомой «именованный конструктор»:

```
class Progression
{
    public float FirstElement { get; }
    public float Difference { get; }

    private Progression(float firstEl, float d)
    {
        FirstElement = firstEl;
        Difference = d;
    }

    static public Progression FromStartAndDiff(float start, float diff)
    {
        return new Progression(start, diff);
    }

    static public Progression FromFormula(Func<int, float> formula)
    {
        return new Progression(formula(1), formula(2) - formula(1));
    }

    static public Progression FromElements(float firstEl, float secondEl)
    {
        return new Progression(firstEl, secondEl - firstEl);
    }
}
```

При этом вы можете создавать объект так:

```
var p1 = Progression.FromStartAndDiff(1, 2);
var p2 = Progression.FromFormula(n => 2 * n - 1);
var p3 = Progression.FromElements(1, 3);
```

Comment: Если из params выволакивать аргументы, то теряется возможность нормального вызова с массивом.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Угу, тогда нужно ещё и перегрузку с `IEnumerable<float>` без `params`.

Comment: Большое спасибо за развернутый ответ. По моей задумке использование `params` обязательно, а также я не планировал пользоваться именоваными конструкторами, поэтому я добавил проверку массива на null внутри конструктора с `params`, и в случае если массив пуст, кидать исключение `ArgumentNullExeption`.

Comment: @PuffyInsolent: Пожалуйста! Вам ещё по идее стоит проверять _длину_ массива, она может быть 0 или 1.